# I need to read a string and get a particular value from it

Tags: java, string, split

This is my String

```
String response =  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1592286483.599</sid>
</response>
```

I want to extract the value of sid from this using this code

```
if (response.contains("sid")) {
            System.out.println("*****************");
            String sid = response.split(">")[2].split("<")[2];
            System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" + sid);
    }
```

I need to get the value of sid from the string. Using this code it is showing

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2     error

Answer (score 1):

The first index should be 3 and the second index should be 0.

```
String sid = response.split(">")[3].split("<")[0];
```

That said, you might consider using an XML parser instead.

Comment: With this

Nothing is getting printed.

Comment: @joshua Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `String#replaceAll`, if you must avoid using an HTML parser:

```
String sid = response.replaceAll("(?s).*<sid>(.*?)</sid>.*", "$1");
System.out.println(sid);
```

This prints: `1592286483.599`

That being said, it might be preferable for you to use an HTML parser, which would avoid the chance that the above goes wrong due to e.g. nested tags, or more than one `<sid>` occurring in the text.

Comment: Using this it is printing this as a sid
~~~

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   256  100    90  100   166     47     87  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   134<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
1592286483.599
</response>
~~~

Comment: @joshua Please see the updated answer, I had a slight problem there, it should work now.

Comment: Yes, this is printing that particular sid only. Thanks
So if the format of my response is always the same will it print the sid correctly?
Also cant we use split method to achieve this?

Comment: @joshua You can use split (I did in my answer), but it's fragile and might break if the response format changes even slightly. Besides, it's less readable. Use an XML parser if you can.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon okay Thankyou
yes the above code works perfectly now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen suppose we have a string with many sid's similar to the format 
String response =  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1592286483.599</sid>
</response>

String response =  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1592286483.609</sid>
</response>

String response =  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1592286483.999</sid>
</response>


and i want the first one to be printed..What we need to change in the code

Comment: Easy, use: `response.replaceFirst("(?s).*?<sid>(.*?)</sid>.*", "$1");` ... this will replace only the first occurrence of `<sid>`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen understood and so what we have to change to get the particular occurrence. Suppose I understood for last and first by using regex and what if I want to replace till the second occurrence of sid?

Comment: This is where I stop.  If you have this requirement, you absolutely should use an XML parser, _not_ regex, and not splitting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But  the demand is I am getting one response as a string 




 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1769  100  1769    0     0   1278      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1278<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results preview='0'>
<meta>


Can i use XML parsing as that % total and all is also there and xml parsing wont work